# working fine in command prompt but not in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, awk, command-prompt

I have to take the field count from particular line in a zip file.
when I queried on command prompt in Linux it gives me output.

```
gunzip -c file | grep 'good' | awk -F' ' '{prinf NF}'
```

when execute this query on command line it gives a output 10 which is correct.

when I assigned this to a variable in shell script and execute .sh it gives me error

```
cat > find.sh
cnt=`gunzip -c file | grep 'good' | awk -F' ' '{print NF}'`
echo $cnt
./ sh find.sh 
find.sh: 2: find sh: 10: not found
```

Please help out in this..!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat find.sh
#!/bin/bash
cnt=$(gunzip -c file | awk '/good/ {prinf NF}')
echo $cnt

./find.sh
10
```